# Working of Digital Analog Clock in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, github, web

I am a beginner and I couldn't understand the working of a Digital analog it left me confused. I was given a clock.png and only the working of clock's hand was a bit complicating.

Javascript -

```
const deg = 6; // setting up the value
const hr = document.querySelector('#hr'); 
const mn = document.querySelector('#mn'); 
const sc = document.querySelector('#sc'); 

setInterval(() => {

    let day = new Date(); 
    let hrs = day.getHours() * 30; 
    let min = day.getMinutes() * deg; 
    let sec = day.getSeconds() * deg; 
    
    hr.style.transform = `rotateZ(${(hrs)+(min/12)}deg)`;
    mn.style.transform = `rotateZ(${min}deg)`;
    sc.style.transform = `rotateZ(${sec}deg)`;

})
```

I just want to know how the set interval Function.

Comment: `setInterval(() => {...}, 1000)` makes the clock tick once every 1000ms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the docs [MDN - setInterval](https://const%20deg%20=%206;%20const%20hr%20=%20document.querySelector(%27.hour-hand%27);%20const%20mn%20=%20document.querySelector(%27.minute-hand%27);%20const%20sc%20=%20document.querySelector(%27.second-hand%27);%20%20setInterval(()%20=%3E%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20let%20day%20=%20new%20Date();%20%20%20%20%20let%20hrs%20=%20day.getHours()%20*%2030;%20%20%20%20%20let%20min%20=%20day.getMinutes()%20*%20deg;%20%20%20%20%20let%20sec%20=%20day.getSeconds()%20*%20deg;%20%20%20%20%20%20//%20Rotating%20the%20hour,%20minute,%20and%20second%20hands%20to%20the%20appropriate%20positions%20%20%20%20%20hr.style.transform%20=%20%60rotateZ($%7Bhrs%20+%20(min%20/%2012)%7Ddeg)%60;%20%20%20%20%20mn.style.transform%20=%20%60rotateZ($%7Bmin%7Ddeg)%60;%20%20%20%20%20sc.style.transform%20=%20%60rotateZ($%7Bsec%7Ddeg)%60;%20%7D,%201000);%20//%20Updating%20the%20clock%20every%201000%20milliseconds%20(1%20second)), `setInterval` has optional second parameter, called `delay` (defined in milliseconds, default value `0`). In your case, internval function needs to be called every second, so you need to pass `1000` as `delay` parameter value.

Below is complete working code, including example HTML/CSS.

```js
const deg = 6;
const hr = document.querySelector('.hour-hand');
const mn = document.querySelector('.minute-hand');
const sc = document.querySelector('.second-hand');

setInterval(() => {
    let day = new Date();
    let hrs = day.getHours() * 30;
    let min = day.getMinutes() * deg;
    let sec = day.getSeconds() * deg;

    // Rotating the hour, minute, and second hands to the appropriate positions
    hr.style.transform = `rotateZ(${hrs + (min / 12)}deg)`;
    mn.style.transform = `rotateZ(${min}deg)`;
    sc.style.transform = `rotateZ(${sec}deg)`;
}, 1000); // Updating the clock every 1000 milliseconds (1 second)
```

```css
.clock-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
}
        
.clock-face {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #333;
}
        
.clock-hand {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    height: 50%;
    top: 00%;
    left: 50%;
    transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
        
.hour-hand {
    width: 8px;
}
        
.minute-hand {
    width: 6px;
}
        
.second-hand {
    width: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="clock-container">
     <div class="clock-face">
         <div class="clock-hand hour-hand"></div>
         <div class="clock-hand minute-hand"></div>
         <div class="clock-hand second-hand"></div>
     </div>
 </div>
```